# ReferenceError : XMLHttpRequest is not defined when running my angular 6 universal app

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have made a Angular 6 project with dependency Angularfire2 .
I am using firestore and firebase storage.
I have converted my app to angular universal and when i run `server.js` it says listening on `localhost:4000` but as soon as i open the browser with `localhost:4200` the terminal shows the following error:

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

[here is the snippet of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhtPP.png)

Comment: Hello, Jayneet! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider posting an [MCVE _(Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example)_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we could help you, instead of posting images of a console output which in no way helps anyone without the code required to reproduce your case.

Answer (score 9):

Install these dependencies:

`npm install --save-dev ws xmlhttprequest`

Then add this to your `server.ts` file

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

If you run into any other issue with SSR by using Firebase, [check if this article already covers it](https://medium.com/@michele.patrassi/angular-ssr-firebase-save-days-of-debugging-by-reading-these-fixes-fcb060e248bb?source=friends_link&sk=62bebf17f7250c3a47d43bfb38f03786).

Sources:

- https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/server-side-rendering-firebase-angular-universal/
- https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angular-6-universal-simple-guide/

Comment: I've the same problem when trying ssr mode of angular (not firebase). 
this solution results in `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. nothing loads . server does not respond.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone gets the same problem, the solution for me was to make sure that I did not import the `HttpClientModule` in my child modules. Once it was already imported in the main `AppModule`, the error went away.

Here is a link that gave me the solution
https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-universal-xmlhttprequest-not-defined-httpclient/

Answer (score 0):

For future reference using `xmlhttprequest` didn't work me so I had to use `xhr2` like so:

1. `npm install ws xhr2 bufferutil utf-8-validate  -D`
2. And then adding both `ws` and `xhr2` to `server.ts`

`(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');`
`(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');`

Comment: I've the same problem when trying ssr mode of angular (not firebase). 
this solution results in `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. nothing loads . server does not respond.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the `@angular/platform-server` and import the `ServerModule`. That provides server implementations of the DOM, XMLHttpRequest, and other low-level features that don't rely on a browser.

For more information see [the universal guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: @jayneetporwal you should share your code, and how you made it 'universal', because it seems like the issue is there

Comment: How to tell angular to use those implementations provided by `ServerModule`. Could you please provide some sample?