# Application Insights in angular universal

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an Angular project and I want to use *Application Insights* for logging.
I have tried this [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/) and it works just fine, **but not in SSR mode**.

When I'm running the application in SSR mode, I get this error:

```
RerefenceError: XmlHttpRequest is not defined
```

I've found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891992/referenceerror-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-when-running-my-angular-6-univers/53599602#53599602), which seems to be the same problem as mine. Following one of its answers, I've installed `XMLHttpRequest` library and added this line to `server.ts`:

```
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

Not working for me. Angular Universal is not responding to *http requests* yet.
Also, I tried to use the 'xhr2' library instead of 'xmlhttprequest`, it didn't work either.

How can I have application insights to work in Angular SSR mode?

---

#### More Detail

This is how I added Application insights to my project.

`monitoring.service.ts`: a wrapper for `ai` APIs:

```js
import { ApplicationInsights } from "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web";

class MonitoringService {
  private appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {
    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
      },
    });
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    // from documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-    monitor/app/javascript#npm-based-setup:
    this.appInsights.trackPageView();
   }
    logException(exception: Error, severityLevel?: number) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.appInsights.trackException({
        exception: exception,
        severityLevel: severityLevel,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And then called the initialization codes of `ai` at `app.component.ts` like this:

```js
import { MonitoringService } from "@shr/services/monitoring.service";
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(
        private appInsightsService: MonitoringService,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId
   ) {
      this.appInsightsService.startMonitoring();
   }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE:

I made it work by surrounding all the method calls related to application insights api, such as `trackException()` and `this.appInsights.loadAppInsights()` within an if statememt:

```js
if (isPlatformBrower(platformId)) {
    // call an api of application insights...
    this.appInights.trackException();
}
```

Using this workaround, I guess none of the exceptions thrown on the server (Angular Universal Server, which is `express` in my case) can be captured by Application Insights. Because the global error handler, calls ai API only if the platform is a browser. What happens if some code being run outside of the browser throws an exception? Is there any way to capture such exception and write it to ai, at some time later when we are back to browser platform?

Comment: Please add the relevant code, links die... and no one wants to parse a random link to guess what you currently have.

Comment: Did you make sure to only include `HttpClientModule` in the root module?

Comment: @David I tried it seperately, not in combination with the solution I mentioned . I'll try them together. thank you for reminding.

Comment: @David Yeap! I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I had already added more details, before it got closed. Do I need to add any other details to reopen my question? anything that may help others answer?

Comment: I used this library [ng-application-insights](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@markpieszak/ng-application-insights) and works fine, also they say the library can be implemented on SSR